# Bitronix with DB2 in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, db2, jta, bitronix

My configuration works fine if I define a datasource bean with driver properties containing driverType as 4.

If I let spring boot auto configuration create the data source bean, data source is created with driver type 2 by default as it's hard coded in the driver.

Is creating a bean explicitly the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the driver class name in application.properties|yml.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Hope that helps:)